# On the iPad, how do I tell what version of Mobile Safari I have?

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari

I'd like to know what precise version of Mobile Safari the iPad I'm using has. Is there any way to find out (preferably from the device itself)? There doesn't seem to be any menu in Safari Mobile, and thus none to choose "About" from. If you go to Settings | Safari, you see various useful things, but no "About" or "Version" or similar, which surprised me.

Comment: +1 good question. Apparently Safari does not support any of the about: pages http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About_URI_scheme

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since [Ross McNab's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/122384/19063) appears to no longer work...

Bookmark this (or any) page - then edit the bookmark - call it what you like, but change the url to...

> javascript:alert(navigator.userAgent)

Now you can check your user agent any time you feel like conveniently from your bookmarks. For iOS 15 you might get a result like this:

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.5 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1

Or if it's just a quick one-off check you want and you're connected to the 'net, do what [T.J. originally posted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/30722/13460).

Comment: This no longer works, as current versions of safari block javascript from being executed in the address bar.

Comment: @r3wt - **This works just fine in Safari on iOS**. Note that Billy's answer **doesn't** have you executing from the address bar. It has you creating a bookmarklet, then running it. That still works, where writing the above directly in the address bar does not.

Comment: Sadly, this no longer works because running JavaScript from the address bar is prohibited now in the latest version. Ironically, I'm still trying to find out what version that actually is... :)

Comment: @Thomas - Works for me on iOS 15.5, which my phone says is the latest. Note this is using a bookmarklet, not (directly) writing JavaScript in the address bar. (The whole point of this answer is that [a previous one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/122384/13460) wrote directly in the address bar and stopped working.) Mind you, the "Safari" version is now just synced to the iOS version, so you can just go look what iOS version you're on.

Answer (score 20):

2022 update: The easiest way these days it to look at what iOS version you're using (Settings > General > Software Update), because it appears that the iOS Safari version is now synced to iOS version (iOS version 15.4's Safari reports it's Version 15.4, 15.5's Safari reports it's Version 15.5, etc.). (Can't find a citation for that, though, sadly.)

---

<s>The only way I've found</s> [Ross McNab's way](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/122384/13460) *was* much better but sadly no longer works (thanks, Apple); [Billy Moon's way](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/175201/13460) works but is a bit awkward for one-off checks.

Another way to do this is to use an external website (there are plenty to choose from, just search on "what's my browser"), which will report my `user-agent` string back to me.

So for instance, these sites will report back to me that my `user-agent` string is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 4_3_5 like Mac OS X; en-gb) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8L1 Safari/6533.18.5
```

...the `Version/5.0.2` part tells me I'm using Mobile Safari 5.0.2.

**Note:** See [Jim Grisham's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/443767/13460) — while this will tell you Safari version, the WebKit version it shows you is apparently no longer accurate.

Comment: I didn't even realize you were answering your own question, but to confirm: yes that would be the only way. You could condense a list of iOS versions and installed Mobile Safari and use that for reference, if no one else has done it already...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, you should probably accept your own answer - it's the best way of doing what you asked.

Comment: Sadly, even this will no longer work: for privacy reasons, all versions of iOS after version 11.4.1 report a maximum WebKit version of 605.1.15.

Comment: _(clarification to my previous comment)_ ~ In February 2018, Apple loosened their policy a bit: WebKit version would still be frozen, but _major_ iOS & Safari versions would remain in the reported `user-agent` http header string; see: _[Release notes; Safari 11.1 (for iOS 11.3 and macOS 13.4)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_11_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH14-SW7)_; also, note that _[“Safari builds upon whatever user-agent string provided by WebKit.”](https://webkit.org/blog/9674/new-webkit-features-in-safari-13/)_.

Answer (score 8):

You can get the userAgent string without visiting an external website, by typing the following in the Safari address bar (where you would normally type a URL):

`javascript:alert(navigator.userAgent)`

You must type it exactly as it appears here, matching case and punctuation.

An alert popup will appear with the full useragent string, which contains the version number of Safari and iOS.

Comment: Sadly, this has stopped working, as [noted by Billy Moon](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30721/on-the-ipad-how-do-i-tell-what-version-of-mobile-safari-i-have/169317?noredirect=1#comment206419_169317). Nowadays you have to create a bookmark, go back and edit it to change the location to the `javascript:alert(navigator.userAgent)` bit, and then follow the bookmark -- *that* still works.

Answer (score 8):

None of the javascript answers worked for me. I found an easier way!
There are several "what's my IP address?" pages out there, such as [this one](http://www.whatismybrowser.com). These pages tell you your IP address and, in some cases, what your browser is, what your operating system is, and if your browser is up to date.

Answer (score 2):

*2022 update:*

For privacy reasons, Mobile Safari on *any* devices with iOS / iPadOS **11.4.1 or later** will only report a *maximum* WebKit version of **605.1.15** in the `User-Agent` string *(I imagine something similar is true for anything accessible via JavaScript)*.

---

If you know the iOS version of the device, the [‘Safari version history’ chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history#iOS/iPadOS) *(or [this archived version](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Safari_version_history&oldid=1189710326))* at Wikipedia is probably the easiest place to look. *(That page contains references for the underlying data sources.)*

*Example:*

> iOS 12.5.5: Safari 12.1.2 / WebKit 607.1.40
> iOS 13.7: Safari 13.1 / WebKit 609.1.20
> iOS 14.7: Safari 14.1.2 / WebKit 611.1.21
> iOS 15.4: Safari 15.4 / WebKit 613.1.17

Comment: The question is about Safari version, not WebKit version, but this WebKit aspect is still useful info.

Comment: Do you have a link for the thing about capping the WebKit version? I believe you, I just like primary sources. :-D

Comment: Since iOS versions, Safari, and WebKit versions are linked, it is important to know the reported WebKit version is frozen; see: _[“On iOS, a publicly released version of WebKit always implies a new rev of the OS; => the version information is more meaningful.”](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=182629#c9)_ and _[“Safari builds upon whatever user-agent string provided by WebKit.”](https://webkit.org/blog/9674/new-webkit-features-in-safari-13/)_.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: See [comment #4 on WebKit bug #212937](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212937#c4). _I believe(?) Chrome was the first to propose this as an anti-‘passive fingerprinting’ measure.)_

Comment: History: 

December 2017: publicly announced freeze of `user-agent` in [Release Notes for Safari Technology Preview 46](https://webkit.org/blog/8042/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-46/) & February  2018: policy loosened somewhat due to community pushback. WebKit version would be frozen, but iOS & Safari version would remain; see: [Release notes; Safari 11.1 (for iOS 11.3 and macOS 13.4)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_11_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH14-SW7)

Comment: Replacements for `user-agent` detections:

1. [Implementing feature detection @ mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Feature_detection)

2. 
A current [draft proposal for ‘ua-client-hints’](https://wicg.github.io/ua-client-hints/) is not currently being developed for WebKit / Safari; see: [Bug 241749: Implement User-Agent Client Hints](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=241749)).

Comment: The version history table is no longer there, it was removed from the wikipedia article in December 2022‎

Comment: Thanks, @chrki; I’ve added an alternate link to help folks *(until the English-language Wikipedia editors resolve their ‘edit war’ over version history table policy)*.

Answer (score 0):

You can visit [http://spiderip.com](https://spiderip.com) to check the user agent and version of safari

Comment: Could you explain why this works, not just a link. Just goiving a link makes me think of viruses and trojans etc.

Comment: This works because on every request the browser send this information to the webserver. But usually you just do not see this and this webpage just "reflects" the information passed via the request.

Answer (score 0):

Handy alternative if you want to copy paste this info / you're already there: plug your iPad into your mac (assuming platform!) and in OSX Safari, remote debug the device, and copy the User Agent from the Resource Panel under Request Headers.

Enable remote debugging:

- In OSX Safari’s Preferences pane under Advanced, check the Show Develop menu in the menu bar checkbox.
- On iDevice: Settings > Safari > Advanced

http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/

Comment: Thanks for this. It took me a while to figure the Resource Panel is on the right edge of the screen (not the Resources tab).

Comment: Unfortunately, I still didn't get any precise versions this way. Just iOS 9.3.2 which I knew anyways. So while I enjoyed your answer, I'm not necessarily recommending it to others. Hope you understand. ,o

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `javascript:alert(navigator.userAgent)` did not work. I tried it but got an error from Safari saying it was not allowed (tested on iOS 12).

I happened to be on jsfiddle.net, typing it in there did work :)

jsfiddle.net is an online website where you can type in JavaScript. And since the JavaScript is coming from the page and not directly from the browser, it is allowed to display.